# Is it normal that adding constraints on the parameters of NonlinearModelFit increases execution time 100 times??

Tags: mathematical-optimization, probability-or-statistics, fitting

Normally, reducing the optimization domain by adding constraints should reduce the time of execution. In my case however, this puts the NonlinearModelFit in a coma. Without constraints, 8 seconds suffice:

```
pobTotal = 4950738;
 mu = 7*41157/365 // N(* weekly births *);
d = mu/pobTotal;
reported = {107, 135, 612, 195, 626, 619, 491, 1164, 1137, 511, 1036, 
   1144, 2650, 3162, 6074, 6693, 8253, 6639, 6148, 4345, 3141, 1958, 
   1130, 484, 356, 296, 195, 121, 208, 101, 67, 128, 20};
data = Thread[{Range[1, 33], reported}];
T = Length[reported ];
mod[\[Gamma]_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_?NumericQ, s0_?NumericQ, 
   i0_?NumericQ] := 
    NDSolveValue[{s'[t] == 
      mu - (\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/pobTotal) - d*s[t],
     i'[t] == (\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/pobTotal) - (\[Gamma] + d)*i[t],
     s[0] == s0,
     i[0] == i0}, {s, i}, {t, 0, 33}, MaxStepSize -> 400][[2]];

Timing[nlm = 
   NonlinearModelFit[
    data, { p*mod[\[Gamma], \[Beta], s0, i0][t]}, {\[Gamma], \[Beta], 
     s0, i0, p}, t]] // Quiet
   
   { \[Gamma]2, \[Beta]2, s02, i02,  
  p2} = { \[Gamma], \[Beta], s0, i0, p} /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

With  constraints:

```
    Timing[nlm2 = 
   NonlinearModelFit[
    data, {p* mod[\[Gamma], \[Beta], s0, i0][t], 1 < \[Gamma] < 1.4 , 
     0 < \[Beta], s0 > 1, 1 < i0, 0 < p},
      {\[Gamma], \[Beta], s0, i0, p}, t]] // Quiet
{\[Gamma]3, \[Beta]3, s03, i03,  
  p3} = {\[Gamma], \[Beta], s0, i0, p} /. nlm2["BestFitParameters"]
```

the execution times gets multiplied by a 100 (900 secs). How to explain this; is it possible to reduce this time?

Comment: Possibly this forced use of a different (slower) optimizer. Also you might want to see if changing from strong to weak inequalities makes a difference.

Comment: Dear  Daniel  Changing the  inequalities did not help. I do not understand what you mean by "forced use of a different (slower) optimizer".  You mean adding constraints forces a change to a different  (default) optimizer?

Comment: A constrained optimization algorithm might need more function evaluations if e.g. it is using a penalty method, or at least in checking if the constraints are not violated.

Comment: Not all optimizers can handle constraints. I was thinking possibly the default might be a quasi-Newton variant and the constrained case might use (typically slower) nonlinear interior point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This concerns the set of equations in your previous questions and those equations impose difficulties with optimizing routines because of the high correlations among the parameter estimators.

Because of those difficulties, if restricting $\gamma$ to a specific range is of interest, it is probably better to set specific values of $\gamma$ *and* use "good" starting values.

For the particular restrictions it appears that the "best" value of $\gamma$ is at the border (which is not atypical).  Below is a plot of the root mean square error (rmse) for various values of $\gamma$ in the restricted range:

```
rmse = Table[{γ0, (NonlinearModelFit[data, {p*mod[γ0, β, s0, i0][t]},
  {{β, 100}, {s0, 86760.5}, {i0, 1.93365}, {p, 1.15771}}, t] // Quiet) 
  ["EstimatedVariance"]^0.5}, {γ0, 1.1, 1.4, 0.01}];
ListPlot[rmse]
```

[image: Plot of root mean square errors for various values of gamma]

So I would "blame" your particular equations and data rather than the addition of restrictions to `NonlinearModelFit`.  (That's not at all to say your equations and data are wrong.  You're just dealing with a difficult situation.)